# Package release issue

Tags: npm, npm-publish, npm-init, npm-login

npm notice Publishing to https://registry.npmjs.org/
npm ERR! code E403
npm ERR! 403 403 Forbidden - PUT https://registry.npmjs.org/demo-package - You do not have permission to publish "demo-package". Are you logged in as the correct user?
npm ERR! 403 In most cases, you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! 403 a package version that is forbidden by your security policy, or
npm ERR! 403 on a server you do not have access to.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/kaleesha/.npm/_logs/2023-01-23T21_12_42_133Z-debug-0.log
I try these steps,
npm init
npm login
npm publish

I have npm account and I logged into it before published the package

Comment: "Are you logged in as the correct user?" `demo-package` sounds like a package you do not own.

Answer (score 1):

`demo-package` is a package that already exists on npmjs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/demo-package). If you are not the user that initially published this package 8 years ago or the user enabled you as a coauthor, you are not allowed to write to it since you are not the owner.

Be aware that npm Packages can not be removed once published on npmjs. There is a very short window to unpublish it. After that, it's not deletable.
If you want to test publishing packages you can try local registries like Verdaccio.